# Confused about deriving the line element

Tags: integration, derivatives, metric-spaces

I wish to use this as my starting point

$$
s=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

and then work my way to the line element $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$, but I cannot understand how to get there.

If I derive $s$, I get

$$
ds=\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

I can equate it to:

$$
sds=xdx+ydy
$$

How do I eliminate the $s,x,y$ such that I end up with $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The line element $ds$ is NOT the exterior derivative of a function $s:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ (or $\Bbb{R}^n$ more generally). The letter $d$ is often used in so many different contexts with so many different meanings that you should not confuse them with each other. In this context, when we write $ds$, we just mean it symbolically, the entire $ds$ should be thought of as a single object, not as $d(s)$. We are not taking the $d$ of something.

One simple example to convince yourself is to take a unit circle $C$ in the plane (oriented in the usual way). Then, $\int_C ds$ is supposed to mean the integration of the constant function $1$ with respect to line element along the curve $C$ (which is simply the length of $C$), which is $2\pi$, however, if the line element really was the $d$ of some function, then this would have to yield $0$ (a simple consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, and using the fact that $C$ is a closed curve), which is obviously not the case.

---

Anyway, the proper way to interpret the $ds$ notation is as follows: given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, the metric tensor $g$ assigns to each $p \in M$ an inner product on the tangent space as  $g_p:T_pM \times T_pM \to \Bbb{R}$. As you probably know from linear algebra, every inner product gives rise to a norm. So, we get a norm on $T_pM$ via $\lVert \cdot\rVert_p:T_pM \to \Bbb{R}$, defined by
\begin{align}
\lVert \xi\rVert_p &:= \sqrt{g_p(\xi,\xi)} & \quad (\xi \in T_pM)
\end{align}
Now, we shall use the notation $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ to mean the function $p\mapsto \lVert \cdot\rVert_p = \sqrt{g_p(\cdot, \cdot)}$ which assigns to each point in the manifold, the norm on the tangent space at that point of the manifold.

Now, with all this introduction out of the way, the meaning of the classical symbol $ds$ in this context is actually $\lVert \cdot \rVert$:
\begin{align}
\text{line element on $M$} &= \text{classically written as $ds$} \\
&= \text{more precisely written as $\lVert \cdot \rVert$, the "norm field" associated to $g$}
\end{align}

In the context of $M= \Bbb{R}^2$ with $g= dx \otimes dx + dy \otimes dy$, we have for $p \in M = \Bbb{R}^2$ and $\xi \in T_pM \cong \Bbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align}
\lVert \xi\rVert_p &= \sqrt{g_p(\xi, \xi)} \\
&= \sqrt{(dx\otimes dx)_p(\xi,\xi) + (dy\otimes dy)_p(\xi,\xi)} \\
&= \sqrt{(dx_p(\xi))^2 + (dy_p(\xi))^2}
\end{align}
Hence, if we suppress the points of evaluation, we get $\lVert \cdot \rVert = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$ (the square root of a quadratic form defined on the various tangent spaces). Or more classically, $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$.

On a slightly related note, when we write $ds^2$, what we mean is the quadratic form associated to $g$; so it is defined pointwise as $(\lVert \cdot \rVert_p)^2$, i.e it is the function
\begin{align}
\xi \mapsto (\lVert \xi\rVert_p)^2 = g_p(\xi,\xi)
\end{align}
See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740078/568204), and the reference to Spivak's differential geometry text (the same pages are relevant here).

---

So, to answer your question directly once again, you can't calculate the line element $ds$ (which is somewhat a confusing use of the notation $d$) by calculating the exterior derivative of the function $s(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.