# Riemannian metric with tensor products

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

I have been studying differential geometry and I came across two different definitions for the Riemannian metric given by:

$$ds^2 = G_{ij} \, dx_i \, dx_j, \tag 1$$

$$ds^2 = G_{ij} \, dx^i \otimes dx^j. \tag 2 $$

Based on the above, I have a few questions:

1. What is the difference between them?
2. What are the advantages of the second definition?
3. What are the properties of the operation $\otimes$?
4. Does the fact of  $dx^i$ and $dx^j$ being orthogonal imply $dx^i\otimes dx^j$ be zero?
5. Based on your vast experience, what are great introductory books that discuss the second definition in the framework of physics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second is more correct. The first is rather lazily written.

Comment: The first is implicitly a symmetric tensor product: $$ dx_i\,dx_j = \frac{1}{2}(dx_i\otimes dx_j + dx_j\otimes dx_i.) $$ That is the standard way to write a Riemannian metric. But, if $G_{ij} = G_{ji}$, which is always assumed, then the two ways are equivalent. Almost any introduction to Riemannian geometry will have a discussion about tensors and the tensor product.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740078/568204) where I also point to specific references (Lee and Spivak, with relevant pages) where you can learn more.

Comment: Hi!@peek-a-boo. I hope you are doing well. How about questions 3 and 4 right above?

Comment: I believe you just asked a new question, and received a great answer there by Ivo. Just to reiterate, you should study the basics of tensors first in vector spaces, and then move on to manifolds (because tensor fields are nothing but smoothly-varying tensors on each tangent space of the manifold).

Comment: Thank you so much @peek-a-boo !