# Is the 2-tensor equivalent of the cross product incomplete in Exercise 8-2.3 of Ted Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics?

Tags: tensors, differential-forms, cross-product

This is exercise 8-2.3 from Ted Shifrin's [Multivariable Mathematics](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Multivariable+Mathematics%3A+Linear+Algebra%2C+Multivariable+Calculus%2C+and+Manifolds-p-9780471526384) (a good book).

> Suppose $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}.$ Show that
> \begin{align*}
> dx\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dy\wedge dz\left(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\right)\\
> dy\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dz\wedge dx\left(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\right)\text{ and }\\
> dz\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dx\wedge dy\left(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\right).
> \end{align*}

In my interpretation of the notation, this isn't correct. (See the
end of this post for a proposed fix.) The cross product is actually
a rank-2 anti-symmetric tensor in this context, so we need three more
components.

I am going to use the notation I typically use so that I don't get
(more?) confused, and so I can copy and paste. Following Wrede (and Schouten), the
symbol $\mathcal{E}_{ijk}$ is the completely anti-symmetric covariant
tensor density ($\approx$Levi-Civita tensor). $E^{ijk}=\mathcal{E}_{ijk}$
is the contravariant counterpart. Indices are raised on basis one-forms
and on contravariant vector components $v^{i}=dx^{i}\left\langle \mathfrak{v}\right\rangle .$
The angle bracket pair is called an "applicator". It specifically
means to apply a vector or form to its argument. It is my own invention (because I don't like hungry operators). Einstein summation is intended.

I am almost certain that the argument list for the two-form above
can be treated as a single tensor product of the two vectors

\begin{align*}
dx\left( \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\right) = & dy\wedge dz\left\langle \mathfrak{v}\otimes\mathfrak{w}\right\rangle \\
= & dx^{2}\wedge dx^{3}\left\langle \mathfrak{v}\mathfrak{w}\right\rangle \\
= & dx^{2}\wedge dx^{3}\left\langle \mathfrak{e}_{k}\mathfrak{e}_{l}\right\rangle v^{k}w^{l}\\
= & dx^{2}\wedge dx^{3}\left\langle \mathfrak{e}_{2}\mathfrak{e}_{3}\right\rangle v^{2}w^{3}\\
= & dy\wedge dz\left\langle \mathfrak{e}_{2}\mathfrak{e}_{3}\right\rangle v^{2}w^{3}\\
= & v^{2}w^{3}.
\end{align*}

Notice that when there is no summation, there is nothing to distinguish $dx\wedge dy$ from $dxdy.$

As an axial vector, the cross product is

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{v}\times\mathfrak{w}= & \mathfrak{e}_{l}\mathcal{E}_{ijk}v^{i}w^{j}\delta^{kl}\\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{i}d\mathit{x}^{i}\langle\mathfrak{v}\times\mathfrak{w}\rangle\\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{m}d\mathit{x}^{m}\left\langle \mathfrak{e}_{l}\right\rangle \mathcal{E}_{ijk}v^{i}w^{j}\delta^{kl}\\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{m}\delta_{l}^{m}\mathcal{E}_{ijk}v^{i}w^{j}\delta^{kl}\\
= & \mathcal{E}_{ijk}v^{i}w^{j}dx^{k}\\
= & \begin{pmatrix}+\left(v^{2}w^{3}-v^{3}w^{2}\right)dx^{1}\\
+\left(v^{3}w^{1}-v^{1}w^{3}\right)dx^{2}\\
+\left(v^{1}w^{2}-v^{2}w^{1}\right)dx^{3}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Note that applying $\mathfrak{e}_{i}d\mathit{x}^{i}$ to a vector
simply returns the vector. This is what Menzel calls the identity
dyadic (tensor). It handles transformations smartly, but can be deceptive. The use of the basis one-forms in the result is algebraically
correct, but should not be taken to mean the cross product is natively
a one-form.  I contend it is natively a bivector.

In order to get the full rank-two tensor equivalent to the cross product
we have to toggle the wedge product by running through the indices. So we write:

\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{T}= & \mathfrak{e}_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j}T^{ij}\\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j}dx^{i}\wedge dx^{j}\left\langle \mathfrak{v}\mathfrak{w}\right\rangle \\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{i}\mathfrak{e}_{j}dx^{i}\wedge dx^{j}\left\langle \mathfrak{e}_{k}\mathfrak{e}_{l}\right\rangle v^{k}w^{l}\\
= & \mathfrak{e}_{i}\wedge\mathfrak{e}_{j}v^{i}w^{j}\\
= & \mathfrak{v}\wedge\mathfrak{w}\\
= & \begin{pmatrix}+\mathfrak{e}_{1}\mathfrak{e}_{2}\left(v^{1}w^{2}-v^{2}w^{1}\right)\\
+\mathfrak{e}_{2}\mathfrak{e}_{3}\left(v^{2}w^{3}-v^{3}w^{2}\right)\\
+\mathfrak{e}_{3}\mathfrak{e}_{1}\left(v^{3}w^{1}-v^{1}w^{3}\right)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

The wedge product of two contravariant vectors is called a bivector.
Clearly both objects have the same information, and since they are
in closed form (all the indices are contracted on a basis) we can
set them equal. But writing the component equations still requires
some work. To convert from the tensor form to the vector form we write

\begin{align*}
T_{k}= & \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{E}_{ijk}T^{ij}\\
= & \mathcal{E}_{ijk}T^{\left\lfloor ij\right\rfloor }.
\end{align*}

The floor brackets on the indices is my way of indicating they are
restricted to increasing order (or any unique selections). The reason
we can now restrict our summation to increasing order is that we have
already done the wedge toggling. We can use the metric $\delta^{ij}$
to raise the index to put it in to contravariant form, if desired.
In general coordinates things are more complicated; so caution is advised.

To get the tensor components from the vector form we simply write

\begin{align*}
T^{ij}= & T_{k}E^{ijk}.
\end{align*}

All that said; **I believe this fixes the exercise:**

\begin{align*}
dx\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dy\wedge dz\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}\mathbf{v}\right),\\
dy\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dz\wedge dx\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}\mathbf{v}\right)\text{and}\\
dz\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & dx\wedge dy\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}\mathbf{v}\right).
\end{align*}

**So, am I correct that, as stated, the proposed result of the exercise
is incorrect? Does my suggestion remedy the problem?**

Note: since we aren't doing any summation using the wedge product,
we don't really need it here. So maybe

\begin{align*}
dx\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & \left(dy\wedge dz+dz\wedge dy\right)\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}\right),\\
dy\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & \left(dz\wedge dx+dx\wedge dz\right)\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}\right)\text{and}\\
dz\left(\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\right)= & \left(dx\wedge dy+dy\wedge dx\right)\left(\mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}\right)?
\end{align*}

Comment: The sentence "when there is no summation, there is nothing to distinguish $\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y$ from $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$" might point to the difference between the book's interpretation of the notation and yours.

Comment: $dx\wedge dy$ eats a pair of vectors and $dz$ eats one vector. You feed $(v,w)$ to the former and $v\times w$ to the latter, what's the problem?  There's nothing wrong with the exercise.

Comment: @IvoTerek have you read my post?

Comment: FYI prof. Shifrin is an active user of this site, if you didn't already know that

Comment: I use neither tensors nor geometric algebra in my text. Your proposed fix is meaningless in the context of my text. My definition is quite clear (and standard): $\omega\in\Lambda^2(\Bbb R^3)$ is an alternating multilinear function of $2$ vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, defined on the top of p. 336 and then — with the wedge notation — on the top of p. 338. Moreover, $dx$ can "eat" only one vector, not a pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exercise is right as it is. Also, the cross product is **by definition** a (bilinear anti-symmetric) mapping $\Bbb{R}^3\times\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^3$. So, the cross product of two vectors is again a vector in the same space. The cross-product of two vectors is not an antisymmetric rank 2 tensor. What is a rank 2 tensor is $v\wedge w\in \bigwedge^2(\Bbb{R}^3)$. Now, one can certainly argue the merits of whether the cross-product should be taught and whether or not it is simpler to just introduce wedge products (at the expense of leaving $\Bbb{R}^3$). My personal view: cross products are unnatural (requiring an inner product and an orientation to define it abstractly) and that in the long run it is more natural to just introduce the exterior algebra so we can more naturally introduce things (especially things like angular velocity, angular momentum, moment of inertia etc). But regardless of our views, the definition still stands: given $v,w\in\Bbb{R}^3$, the object $v\times w$ is defined to be an element of $\Bbb{R}^3$ (by the usual ad-hoc prescription).

So, you trying to write $dx(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$ is just wrong from the beginning (also, why bother with tensor densities? they serve no purpose here, and also the Levi-Civita tensor is simply another name for the volume form, which in the case of $\Bbb{R}^3$ is just $\det$ thought of as an alternating $3$-multilinear map on $\Bbb{R}^3$). Anyway, here’s how we can calculate things:
\begin{align}
dx(\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{w})&=dx\bigg((v^2w^3-v^3w^2)\mathbf{e}_1+ (\cdots)\mathbf{e}_2 + (\cdots)\mathbf{e}_3\bigg)\\
&=(v^2w^3-v^3w^2)\cdot 1+(\cdots)\cdot 0+(\cdots)\cdot 0\\
&=v^2w^3-v^3w^2\\
&=dy(\mathbf{v})\cdot dz(\mathbf{w})-dz(\mathbf{v})\cdot dy(\mathbf{w})\\
&=(dy\otimes dz)(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})-(dz\otimes dy)(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\\
&=(dy\otimes dz-dz\otimes dy)(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\\
&=:(dy\wedge dz)(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}).
\end{align}
The last equality is simply a definition of the wedge product of two 1-forms. You seem to think $dy\wedge dz=dy dz=dy\otimes dz$, which couldn’t be further from the truth. So, you really just have to unwind the definitions here. It really is a trivial exercise, and the other two identities follow just as easily.

Comment: Your interpretation is in agreement with MTW 3.5.  I forgot about that.  I don't see where Dr. Shifrin defined the application of the wedge product before that point in the text.  So I'm still protesting.  I think the exercise needs to define the application of wedge, unless the use the $\wedge$ was explained in a previous chapter.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I don’t have the text, so I won’t comment on that, but if I remember correctly, his lectures on youtube definitely go through wedge products and stuff. In any case, this is all standard stuff, so you can find it in a variety of texts (Spivak, Munkres, Loomis& Sternberg, Lee, Cartan…)

Comment: (,) was a sticky keyboard and one too many undo steps. As for treating the cross product as a vector, verses a bivector, I think both concepts are useful.  As an oriented surface patch, the bivector concept is more useful.  When dealing with rotations of rigid bodies, having an arrow along the axis of rotation is conceptually useful.  https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf  Of course the treatment of a bivector as a vector is unique to three dimensions.

Comment: I'm beginning to waver on my accepting the answer.  The definition for basis 1-forms is $dx^{i}\wedge dx^{j}:=-dx^{j}\wedge dx^{i}.$  What is the expansion of $a_i b_j \left(d\mathit{x}^i\otimes d\mathit{x}^j-d\mathit{x}^j\otimes d\mathit{x}^i\right)?$

Comment: What you wrote is not the definition of wedge products. That is a property of wedge products (anti-symmetry). The definition is as I wrote it. If you don't believe me, I gave you a bunch of texts you can look up. Loomis and Sternberg is freely available online (chapter 7 is on multilinear algebra). Wedge products are by definition the alternation of tensor products.

Comment: Oh.  I forgot $dx\wedge dy= -dy\wedge dx$ but $dxdy\ne dydx$.

Comment: Actually, Shifrin gives a different definition of $d\mathbf{x}_I\left(\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_k\right)=det \left(\mathbf{v}_1\otimes\dots\otimes\mathbf{v}_k\right)$

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton what do *you* mean by the symbol $dxdy$? If you mean $dx\otimes dy$, then indeed, you can’t commute them. However, sometimes, people mean the symmetrized tensor product $dx\,dy:=\frac{dx\otimes dy+dy\otimes dx}{2}$, in which case $dx\,dy=dy\,dx$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3740078/568204) for similar remarks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142258/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-steven-thomas-hatton).

Comment: What you claim is my definition is NOT. And I don't know what the determinant of a $k$-tensor is, by the way. Where in your interpretation of my definition does the multiindex $I$ appear? I never use tensors in my text, and I write $dx\,dy$ only in the context of double integration.

Comment: @TedShifrin I stand corrected.  I did some front-end preprocessing in that statement.  Its what we end up doing.  The determinant is simply the alternating sum of all the terms of the tensor product.  This is what I was intending $\delta_{j_{1}\ldots j_{k}}^{i_{1}\dots i_{k}}v_{1}^{j_{1}}\ldots v_{k}^{j_{k}},$ using the alternating generalized Kronecker delta.

Comment: By the way, since I was writing this text predominantly for first- and second-year undergraduates, I purposely avoided tensors and tensor products and tried to make the formalism of exterior algebra and differential forms as concrete as possible. I obviously used the "fancier" approach when doing more advanced courses.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think your definition of the wedge product is great. Perhaps ideal.  I confused myself by trying to relate it to what I already know, rather than paying attention to the logical sequence of your presentation.  A year ago, I knew how to correctly use the wedge product in the context of the exercise.  Apparently  the identification of the wedge product with the determinant didn't stick.  I hope that my embarrassment will shore up my retention.